# Closed form of $\sum _{k=1}^{n }\:\lfloor{n/k}\rfloor$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions, summation-method

I came across a question in which, if I am able to calculate this sum,

> $\sum_{k=1}^{n }\:\lfloor{n/k}\rfloor=$ ?

it would get solved quite easily. I have never seen any closed form for this question, (though I saw a simplification by a previous answer:
$\sum_{k=1}^{n }\:\lfloor{n/k}\rfloor=2\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor }\:\lfloor{n/k}\rfloor-\lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor^2$).

I was wondering, does there exist any closed form or other simplified ways of calculation for this sum?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your sum is not defined when $k=0$.

Comment: My apologies, I meant $k=1$.

Comment: Look at https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C5%2C8%2C10%2C14%2C16%2C20%2C23%2C27&language=french&go=Chercher

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is the [divisor summary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function), its closed form is not known. Even its leading error bound is a famous open problem.

Comment: @achillehui Thanks!